# Changing a password on a web interface with protection to replay attacks

Tags: algorithm, encryption, sha1

I have a web application (ExtJS+perl) that has a "Change password" dialog. I want to implement the password changing in such a way that even if the traffic is sniffed and the new password hash is intercepted, the attacker can't do anything with it.

I'm not using https, so I must figure out a different way to obfuscate the new password hash. Here is how the current login works:

- the client requests a challenge from the server (e.g: 031fee1c)
- the client encrypts the password with this algorithm:

  hash=sha1(sha1(clearPassword)+challenge)
- the client sends the hash and is authenticated by the server

This prevents replay attacks, since the hash will not work without the challenge (the server knows just sha1(clearPassword).

I'd like to do something similar when changing passwords. The client can encrypt the password with sha1, but if it sends it like this and it is intercepted, it can be used to calculate the login hash each time.

Any ideas/suggestions on how I should send the new encrypted password back to the server?

Comment: Why are you not using https?  Apart from the obvious re-invention of the wheel and the likelyhood of introducing a security holes (even if you are a security expert), **training users that anything other than a `https` connection is secure is a bad idea**.  Also you leave yourself open to man-in-the middle attacks.

Comment: "the client encrypts the password with this algorithm" - how do you do the check on the server later? are you storing plain passwords?

Comment: I can't use https for now because I don't have proper signed certificates (and self-signed won't do). I know https would be a great solution, but I wanted to know if there was another way of doing it securely... Guess not...

Comment: @Adrian If the issue with SSL certificates is the price then you might want to take a look at http://www.startssl.com/, or possibly http://www.cheapssls.com/ or better still ask on SuperServerfault.com.  It should be possible to obtain a certificate for public use at a reasonable price.

Comment: So your users are important enough to spend many hours of your time to hack together a makeshift solution, but not important enough to warrant buying a cheap SSL certificate?

Comment: Also, in your current authentication scheme, sha1(clearpassword) _is_ the password. Adding an additional layer of hashing doesn't gain you anything, and illustrates perfectly the hazards of cooking up your own crypto.

Comment: @Nick – The inner hash is what the server stores, which prevents your cleartext password being revealed if the server is compromised. PBKDF2 would be much, much better, of course.

Comment: @aaz My point is that the cleartext password is irrelevant - if the hash leaks, the attacker can use the hash to authenticate themselves. The cleartext password is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @Nick – Yes, to this single site. But people often use the same or similar passwords on multiple sites. (This scheme is like a simplified HTTP digest authentication.)

Comment: @aaz That's completely irrelevant. In this scheme, the hash _is_ the password. With the hash, the attacker can do anything they could do with the password itself. The scheme adds absolutely no additional security over storing the password in plaintext.

Comment: @Nick – This adds absolutely no security to this single site. But, as a user, I find it desirable that servers don't store my plaintext password. I also prefer that my authentication cannot be replayed. This achieves both properties. Or think of it this way: by hashing my password with the site name (which isn't done here, but should be), I can generate a distinct key for each site I visit from a single secret master password.

Comment: @aaz First off, this isn't part of the threat model for this site. Second, if other sites used this protocol, they'd be just as vulnerable. Third, an unsalted password is extremely easy to crack. There are existing protocols, such as digest auth, that provide better _actual_ security.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own public key crypto. For example, do a Diffie-Hellman key exchange and encypt your `SHA-1(new password)`. I'm not sure if there's a good library for it, but it is relatively simple, as [this example](http://www.soa-world.de/echelon/2010/09/diffie-hellman-key-exchange-in-javascript.html) shows. Note that in real code you would use [different values](http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2009-06-11-cryptographic-right-answers.html) (scroll to "Diffie-Hellman") for `p` and `g` and choose `a` and `b` randomly between `2` and `p-2`.

However, JavaScript crypto is usually [a bad idea](http://rdist.root.org/2010/11/29/final-post-on-javascript-crypto/). Basically, a man-in-the-middle could modify your JavaScript to send a copy of the unhashed password somewhere.

This applies to your current login scheme too. You may want to consider replacing it with [digest authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication) so that the user enters the password into a browser dialog box instead of on the page.

A self-signed certificate is actually a better solution than any of this, because then the user accepts the certificate once and later the browser verifies it every time. (This is how most of us use SSH.)

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! I will consider switching to SSL with a self-signed/cheap certificate.